# The Controller ActionResult not called from partial_view just in new tab

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, partial-views, url.action

I have a partial view as a side menu.
From that I want to call a Controller method when I click to the link.
Now it's doing nothing, not hitting the breakpoit in the controller. BUT if I click on the link with right click and select "open in new tab", it works fine in a new tab.

Could you please help me in this ?

In the side menu view:
<a class="Detailed_side" href="@Url.Action("ChangeProfile", "Account", new {profileId = selectedId})">

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ChangeProfile(long profileId)
        {
            SetProfile(profileId);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've found the solution, there was a little difference in the container divs